# Figma: stroke length in percents - is it possible?

Tags: stroke, figma

Can you help me make stroke on rectangle (with rounded corners) but not all the rectangle, only part of it (for example 74% of shape stroke length)?
Thank you for help!

May be there is some plugin...

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V480G.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the same as your example, but the closest I can get.

Use the arc feature of the ellipsis, together with a mask on the rectangle shape to make it seem like your filling it in with a stroke. There's a lot of downsides here so I would do it differently, but if you **need** it to be set with a percentage, this *can* work.

[image]